# SASS media query mixin combination

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS mixin for media queries which works well, especially when nesting, but the issue is I can't seem to work out how I could write my mixin so I can combine different media queries. Is there a way in which I can keep the simplicity of my mixin but allow for multiple combined queries?

For example:

```
@include media(tablet-p) and media(phone) {
     width: 100%;
}
```

This is my current mixin below including how I use it currently.

```
@mixin media($size) {
    @if $size == laptop {
        @media screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else if $size == tablet-l {
        @media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else if $size == tablet-p {
        @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else if $size == phone {
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@include media(phone) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being rude or so please dont take it like that but that is no a simple mixin, or flexible.

Have a variables or a map of your breakpoints, and a mixin that takes those. I work with mobile first so I always start with mobile styles so my most used cases are `small`, `medium` that is `min-width`. Sometimes of cause you have to use `to-small` ect..

```
$breakpoints: (
  'to-small'      : ( max-width:  766px ),
  'small'         : ( min-width:  767px ),
  'to-medium'     : ( max-width:  991px ),
  'medium'        : ( min-width:  992px ),
  'to-large'      : ( min-width: 1199px ),
  'large'         : ( min-width: 1200px ),
  'to-x-large'    : ( min-width: 1599px ),
  'x-large'       : ( min-width: 1600px )
);
```

mixin

```
@mixin media($breakpoint) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint))} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else {
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map.";
  }
}
```

Usage

```
.block {
  width: 100%;

  // this query will apply from widths larger then 1200px
  // meaning you have the same for mobile and tablet
  @include media('large') {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.block {
  width: 100%;

  // this query will apply from widths larger then 992px (landscape tablet)
  // meaning you have the same for mobile and tablet portrait
  @include media('medium') {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand. Can you use multiple media queries in your example to make the width 25% on various sizes?

Comment: I haven't seen that used before so I would say no, but I could be wrong. Eitherway I would never want to mix media queries even if it was possible :). @JohnthePainter

Comment: Why not? Sometimes the same styles apply for phone as they would for tablet portrait so you'd have to write everything twice otherwise?

Comment: @JohnthePainter depends how you structure your css. Let me update my answer with a better example